# Dll injection not working in suspended process

Tags: dll-injection, createremotethread

I'm using CreateRemoteThread api to inject a dll into a process. This works when the process is running state. But If I launch a process in suspended state using CreateProcess api and try to inject a dll into it, then dll injection is not working. But If I use createprocess without suspended flag, then I can able to inject the dll.
Can anyone tell me the solution of this problem?

Comment: Strange question. This is obvious, isn't it? To load a DLL you must call LoadLibrary(). How do you expect this to work in a process that is dead?

Comment: I'm referring to the dll-injection method using createremotethread. This method infact uses loadlibrary API. http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/using-createremotethread-for-dll-injection-on-windows/

Comment: @K07 Did you figure this out in the end?

Comment: Nope, I stopped working . The dll-injection did work on other machines though I don't know the reason behind that.

Comment: This might be of some help: https://opcode0x90.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/injecting-dll-into-process-on-load/

Answer (score 2):

I meet the similar case. Not know the exact root cause, I suggest you to try to use QueueUserAPC api to do the injection.

Comment: Will also not work. You cannot do ANYTHING in a suspended process. The process must be running to load a DLL.

Answer (score 2):

It can not work because creating a process with suspended flag,it loads only ntdll.dll.
kernal32.dll is not loaded yet, so you can not use createprocess to call LoadLibrary(in the kernal32.dll) in the remote suspended process.
but you can use LdrLoadDll(in the ntdll.dll) instead.
you can also use QueueUserAPC with LdrLoadDll ,too. it will works well~